# Multiple Credentials? OAuth? What defines a "project?"

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-bigquery, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api, credentials

So I have an application that I want to be able to read from BigQuery and perform queries, be able to read from GSheets to form these queries and upload this data into a directory in Google Drive.

I understand how to individually do these things, but for the sake of consolidating my system, I would like to use one set of credentials for everything. Is this a good way to go about building my system? I would like to follow the "least access possible" guideline to limit visibility to the database.

Is the best way to go about this creating multiple credentials? Should I use OAuth Credentials and include relevant scopes? Or can I create one set of credentials for all of this?

I'm using python for the backend, don't think that's relevant to the question though.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to handle this is to create the project using the *Google API Console* and authorize all the APIs needed for this project.

Afterwards, you will have to select the APIs needed by following the steps from this article [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/authorizing#OAuth2Authorizing).

In order to retrieve the credentials for the project, you will have to select the project you created and based on the type of application you plan on developing, you will have to select the type of credentials needed.

*Selecting APIs & Service*

[image: select credentials]

*Selecting Credentials*

[image: credentials types]

Then based on your choice, you will end up retrieving the credentials and use them in your application.

#### Reference

- [Authorize Requests](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication).